# conditional expectation coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

A 10-yen coin is thrown $N$ times, where $N$ is the number of total heads of obtained by tossing three $100$-yen coins together. Calculate the expected value of the number of total heads obtained by tossing the $10$ yen coin.

**My attempt**
Let $10$ yen coin be thrown $N$ times $= X_1+X_2+X_n$

$E(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i)\mbox{ for } i=1,2,3 $

$P(N=k)$ is for total of head when three 100 yen coin is tossed.

$$\begin{aligned}
P(N=0) &= \frac18 \\
P(N=1) &= \frac38 \\
P(N=2) &= \frac38 \\
P(N=3) &=\frac18 \\
P(N=k) &\approx \frac32 \end{aligned} \\
P(\text{number of total 100 yen head})\cdot E(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i\mid P(N=k)) \\
E(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i)=P(N=k) \cdot E(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i\mid P(N=k)$$

Is this right? What should I do next? I'm quite confused, of the relation of N and expectation

Answer is $3/4$, but how can I find it?

I computed expectation, $N$ for $10$ yen is 
$$\begin{aligned}
N &= 0~, & 0.5 \cdot 0 &= 0 \\
N &= 1~, & 0.5  \\
N &= 2~, & 0.5 \cdot 2 & \\
N &= 3~, & 0.5 \cdot 3 & \end{aligned} \\
P(\text{number of total 100 yen head}) \cdot E(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i\mid P(N=k))
= 0 \cdot \frac18 + \frac3 8 \cdot 0.5 + \frac38 \cdot1 + \frac18 \cdot 1.5$$
am I right??

Comment: Hint: condition on $N$ and use $E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$.

Comment: @StanTendijck can you elaborate more? i dont know how can i find this  $E(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i|P(N=k))$ and i got $P(N=k)~=\frac{3}{2}$ is this right?

Comment: I suggest to improve the presentation of the question and the english. The question is not very clear...

Comment: I agree with Thomas. Btw you don't condition on $P(N=k)$ but on the actual scenario $N=k$.

Comment: @Thomas i edit a little bit , is it better?

Comment: @StanTendijck what do you mean by actual scenario? there is possibility i= 0 ,1,2,3 right?

Comment: There are still lots of notational mistakes in your question. However, you end up with the correct calculation in the end, although I would write it like: $$E\left[\sum_i X_i\right] = E\left[E\left[\sum_i X_i|N\right]\right] = \sum_{n} P(N=n)E\left[\sum_i X_i|N=n\right]=1/8\cdot 0 + \cdots + 1/8\cdot 1.5.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the count of heads on the $N$ coins, where $N$ is the count of heads on tossing three coins (all coins being fair and independent).   So $N\sim\mathcal{Bin}(3,1/2)$ and $X\mid N\sim\mathcal{Bin}(N,1/2)$.

We seek $\mathsf E(X)$ and by the Law of Total Probability: $$\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid N))$$

The expectation for a Binomially distributed random variable is well known, so this will be easy enough for you to evaluate.